# Better method for flipping multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've retrieved some data from the database, which is in the following structure:

```
[0]
  [item_id] = 197
  [dice_chat_css] = "foo"
  [dice_image] = "bar.png"
[1]
  [item_id] = 128
  [dice_chat_css] = "foo"
  [dice_image] = "bar.png"
```

The most convenient and computationally inexpensive way for me to pass this data to the rest of my (PHP) application is with `item_id` as the index, because it saves having to loop over the array to look up values. If this was a flat array, I could accomplish this trivially with `array_flip`, but since it isn't, it's my pick of using either the multidimensional array_flip [listed in the comments on PHP.net,](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php#107097) or roll my own logic:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($r); $i++){
    $s[$r[$i]['item_id']]['dice_image'] = $r[$i]['dice_image'];
    $s[$r[$i]['item_id']]['dice_chat_css'] = $r[$i]['dice_chat_css'];
}
```

I know it's simple, but it feels like I'm reinventing the wheel here. Is there an accepted, more optimized method available or am I being weird about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do

```
$indexed = array();
foreach ($r as $row) {
    $indexed[$row['item_id']] = $row;
}

// or if you're concerned about memory (e.g. result set is large), less smooth version:
foreach ($r as $index => $row) {
    $r[$row['item_id']] = $row;
    unset($r[$index]);    // it works ok, foreach doesn't traverse over added elements, but it isn't a good way
}

// or smoother alternative for unset(), have second array contain links to first:
$indexed = array();
foreach ($r as &$row) {
    $indexed[$row['item_id']] = &$row;
}
```

Comment: You could add `unset($row['item_id'])` to remove the id from the entry itself

Comment: @Eric Sure, but that usually is redundant. It doesn't eat much memory and still is sometimes useful when it's easier to not store index of currently used row in a separate variable.

Comment: Ultimately I prefer my for() flow, but I believe you did confirm for me that simply iterating through the array is the proper solution.